# Redirect jvm warnings to stderr rather than stdout

Tags: java, jvm

My application uses stdout for IPC, however it is printing the following jvm warning to stdout rather than to stderr.

```
[0.002s][warning][os,container] Duplicate cpuset controllers detected. Picking /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset, skipping /tmp/nix-chroot.NLllBL/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.
```

I am running it currently via `java -jar <jar-file>` with OpenJDK 17.

What option is required to either quiet this or print any errors to stderr.

Additionally if anyone knows, what the rationale behind printing to stdout rather than stderr here is, I would be very interested to know, because my understanding of the convention is that stdout is for the programs intended output, while stderr is for operator information such as warnings or errors.

Comment: You say "jvm warning". Are you saying that it's not from the Java *app* itself? Does it disappear with `java -jar foo.jar >/dev/null`?

Comment: See https://bugs-stage.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8270087 - They describe a workaround.

Comment: @g00se yes it does (when I redirect stdout to a file it also gets redirected)

Comment: If the workarounds mentioned don't work, you could try the really kludgy `java -jar foo.jar | sed '/Duplicate cpuset controllers detected/d'` ;)